# SQL query by compound index

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table `items` with columns `id` `type` `number` `room`, `id` is primary key, `(type, number)` is a unique compound key; And a table `inventory` with columns `id`, `item_type`, `item_number`, `owner`, `id` is primary key, `(type, number)` is a unique compound key.

Example:

`items`

```
| id | type    | number | room |
+----+---------+--------+------+
|  1 |  laptop |      1 |   12 |
|  2 |  laptop |      2 |   13 |
|  3 | desktop |      1 |   13 |
```

`inventory`

```
| id | item_type | item_number | owner |
+----+-----------+-------------+-------+
|  1 |    laptop |           1 |   Joe |
|  2 |    laptop |           2 |   Joe |
|  3 |   desktop |           1 | Susan |
```

How do I query all `items` owned by Joe? If I do

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE (type, number) IN (
    SELECT item_type, item_number FROM inventory WHERE owner = 'Joe'
)
```

I only get one row in the result, though subquery returns multiple rows. I can't seem to do `join` on multiple columns either, like

```
SELECT *
FROM items
JOIN inventory ON inventory.item_type = items.type,
    inventory.item_number = items.number`
WHERE inventory.owner = 'Joe'
```

Comment: And why can't you join on multiple columns?  What is the problem?

Comment: syntax error at or near "="

Comment: You ought to combine the join conditions with AND, not with a comma.

Comment: Great! Such a stupid error... Post it as an answer so I could accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ought to combine the join conditions with AND, not with a comma.